# I cannot install Geoplot in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, python

I cannot install Geoplot Lib (Python lib) in Ubuntu in 20.04. I used pip installer and conda, It says my CUDA Driver version, 10.02 isn't incompatible.. Help me please. It says proj and cartopy library versions are not compatible but I have the latest versions of them

Comment: Is this software in the software center? If not, you might elaborate a bit on the software (what is it, where did you download, how do you attempt to install, what are the errors you get, ...) in order to increase your chance on an answer.

Comment: Geoplot is a python library used for spatial representation n projection